# Obtener usuarios que no pertenezcan a un rol Spatie - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

tengo este problema, como puedo obtener todos los usuarios que no pertenezcan a un rol, por ejemplo:
tengo 3 roles: admin, vendedor y tiendas, lo que quiero es obtener los usuarios que no tengan el rol tiendas, pero no se como hacerlo con spatie.
Por ahora hice esto

```
\App\User::role(['Cashier','Admin']);
```

Pero cuando se agregue otro rol y usuarios a este, no se van a mostrar ese es el detalle.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes [Consultar la Ausencia de Relación](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence).

```
User::whereDoesntHave('roles', function ($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'tiendas');
})->get();
```

Fuente: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/issues/130#issuecomment-256489305